# CC.NET File merge task and dynamic values

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config, continuous-integration

How can I use CCNetLabel in the file merge task? From what I have found I have to use dynamicValues. I have something like this and it is not working any help?

```
<publishers>
  <merge>
    <dynamicValues>
      <replacementValue property="files">
        <format>D:\Testoutput\{0}\*.xml</format>
        <parameters>
          <namedValue name="$CCNetLabel" value="Default" />
        </parameters>
      </replacementValue>
    </dynamicValues>
  </merge>
  <xmllogger />
  <modificationHistory onlyLogWhenChangesFound="true" />
  <statistics />
</publishers>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your script you're trying to generate the following configuration (intentionally I'm using the shorthand notation which is easier to read):

```
<publishers>
  <merge>
    <files>D:\Testoutput\$[$CCNetLabel]\*.xml</files>
  </merge>
  <xmllogger />
  <modificationHistory onlyLogWhenChangesFound="true" />
  <statistics />
</publishers>
```

This won't work because `<files>` is an array, therefore you'd need something like:

```
<publishers>
  <merge>
    <files>
      <file>D:\Testoutput\$[$CCNetLabel]\*.xml</file>
    </files>
  </merge>
  <xmllogger />
  <modificationHistory onlyLogWhenChangesFound="true" />
  <statistics />
</publishers>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work either because `<dynamicValues>` are supported only for the `<merge>` but not for the `<files>` tag. I don't think it's currently (version 1.6) possible to use integration properties here at all.

I'd use the following workaround to achieve the same result:

```
<publishers>
  <exec>
    <executable>C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe</executable>
    <buildArgs>/C copy D:\Testoutput\$[$CCNetLabel]\*.xml D:\Testoutput\FixedDir</buildArgs>
  </exec>
  <merge>
    <files>
      <file>D:\Testoutput\FixedDir\*.xml</file>
    </files>
  </merge>
  <xmllogger />
  <modificationHistory onlyLogWhenChangesFound="true" />
  <statistics />
  <exec>
    <executable>C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe</executable>
    <buildArgs>/C del D:\Testoutput\FixedDir\*.xml</buildArgs>
  </exec>
</publishers>
```