# CruiseControl.net file merge issue

Tags: xml, cruisecontrol.net

I am having an issue trying to merge the outputs of FxCop, StyleCop and a few other xml files into the build.

My configuration looks like this:

```
<publishers> 
    <merge>
     <files>
            <file>$(ArtifactsFolder)\$(ProjectName)\$(CCBuildVersion)\logs\*.xml</file>
     </files>
 </merge>
    <xmllogger logDir="$(ArtifactsFolder)\$(ProjectName)\$(CCBuildVersion)\logs"/>
</publishers>
```

The $(CCBuildVersion) comes from the ccnet.config file which looks like this:

```
<cb:define CCBuildVersion="$[$CCNetLabel]" />
```

A few things to tell you before you start answering:

- The xml files DO exist and are in the same directory as the outputted build log from ccnet
- The xml files seem to be valid, I cannot find anything wrong other than StyleCop has no Xml descriptor at the top, it just goes directly into the root node

The only thing I can think of is that because I am using a dynamic variable that it may not get the right directory when it parses the configuration, but that being said, everything outputs in the right place...

I have gone over EVERY line in the temp log, and have found the following:

```
2011-10-27 09:50:23,724 [ProjectName:ERROR] Publisher threw exception: System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Tasks.MergeFileInfo'.
   at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Tasks.DynamicValueUtility.PropertyValue.ChangePropertyValue(Object value)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Tasks.DynamicValueUtility.PropertyValue.ChangeProperty(Object value)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Tasks.ReplacementDynamicValue.ApplyTo(Object value, Dictionary`2 parameters, IEnumerable`1 parameterDefinitions)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Tasks.TaskBase.ApplyParameters(Dictionary`2 parameters, IEnumerable`1 parameterDefinitions)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Project.PublishResults(IIntegrationResult result, Dictionary`2 parameterValues)
```

Tried googling it and not getting any relevant matches, anyone ever had this before?

Answer (score 1):

Wild cards are supported.

See this for a work-around to a bug in ccnet:
[CC.NET File merge task and dynamic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569614/cc-net-file-merge-task-and-dynamic-values)

See this for the bug report:
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/issues/99

Answer (score 0):

Does the "file" node allow wildcards? (I didn't think that feature existed, though I could be wrong.)  You might try a merge with a single filename using the variables.

Edit: You are defining CCBuildVersion to be the same as CCNetLabel - have you tried just using CCNetLabel directly?

Comment: Was doing that originally, but then saw about 5 examples which used wildcards, so tried that instead.

Comment: Still doesn't do anything, out of curiosity the line where I define $[$CCNetLabel], I tried to default this to "default" i.e $[$CCNetLabel|default], as in the documentation this *should* work, but it doesn't and the server wont start saying something about invalid symbols. It is just I always get a folder called $[$CCNetLabel] in the artifacts root.

Comment: The CCNetLabel is not populated until Runtime, so apparently you have to do it the way I have done, I would much rather use the original variable but it has problems with runtime setting of things :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't seem like you can put wildCard :

http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/File%20Merge%20Task.html